# How to stretch svg text vertically

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg text which I need to stretch both horizontally and vertically. I was able to stretch the word horizontally using the `text-length` property but I couldn't find a way to stretch it vertically.

```
<svg width="300px" ... >
   <text textLength="300px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" > HELLO </text>
</svg>
```

[image]
I want to stretch this text vertically to fill the grey area. Is this doable? If so what is the path?

I have created a plunker for this-> [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yNH3Om?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `height`?

Comment: Yes, I added the height property for the `text` element but it did not do any thing.

Comment: Please show all of your code and/or create a plunkr of your issue

Comment: I added a plunkr

Comment: What does vary exactly in your setup? The container width only? In that case, just set your viewBox correctly and set preserveAspectRatio to none: https://plnkr.co/edit/bbEgId7zJhFkeMkHKU1w?p=preview But if the text vary, then it'll get harder.

Comment: setting the viewbox correctly worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scale(x,y) transform command to scale an element. A scale of 1 is normal size, 0.5 is half normal size, and 2 is double normal size.

```
<text transform="scale(1, 2)" textLength="300px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" > HELLO </text>
```

Comment: the thing is the height can be vary. So I can't hard code it. Can I decide it depend on the height?